# Accounts package doesn't work in meteorite 0.5.9 test release

Tags: meteor, release, accounts

I have been working on meteor since the 0.5.1 release. Now with the 0.6.x releases some of my functions don't work any more...
With the Meteor --release I can only simulate 0.6.0, but not 0.5.7 for example... 
I tried meteorite with

```
mrt create test --tag v0.5.9
```

and it is starting correctly in the created test folder. But the accounts-password package doesn't work. Creating a new account or logging in is only loading...

Anyone an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit like an issue introduced by [variable scoping in version 0.6.0 of meteor](http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/04/04/meteor-060-brand-new-distribution-system-app-packages-npm-integration). From Meteor version 0.6.0 a files variables are localized to that file. This means other files can't access another files variables/functions unless that variables/functions are global.

You would need to look for variables declared in the form:

```
var data = true;
```

and change that to

```
data = true;
```

The same goes for functions. If you have

```
function xyz() {...}
```

You need to change it to

```
xyz = function() {...}
```

Once you sort this out in your code it ought to work. Keep in mind this change in Meteor 0.6.0 can also help you organize your files better & keep code cleaner. So you could make global only the functions necessary and modularize your meteor application.

Comment: Yes, of course the functions don't work anymore, because they are not public. But is there a way to simulate an older release?